# Add Change role button for list of user in an event

Tags: functions, users, user-roles

[image]
I need a custom code function which upgrade user role in bulky action just like the default Wordpress change role function in all user Wordpress section

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to get the code which make up the button but it’s not changing the role it’s redirect to empty page

Comment: Don’t you forget am trying to effect this functionality in a plugin called espresso event plugin under the template which list users who register for an event